# Upgrade an application through itunes instead of directly downloading the update inside iPad

Tags: itunes, software-update, ipad

There is an application (a game) I have installed on iPad through iTunes, now I want to download an update for that game, but since my Wi-fi is not working is there someway I can connect the iPad to my PC and download & install the update through itunes or through some other way (apart from fixing my wi-fi :-) ).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From iTunes, enter the iTunes Store, and search for the app you want to update in the App Store. Once you have found it, redownload it (with the updated version). Then connect your iPad to your PC with the USB cable and sync it. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. the problem is the game has different levels and after the particular level is unlocked it is downloaded and the application is upgraded. Re-downloading won't help here, it helps if there is some bug-fixes or other updates to the application as a whole but not in this case.